Issue with number formatting in Laravel controller
I am working with a Laravel controller where I am restricting the number of decimal places to 2. Here is an example:
$number = 123.456789; // Example number

// Format the number to 2 decimal places
$formatted_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');

// Cast the formatted number to a float
$float_number = (float) $formatted_number;

echo $float_number;

When I send the response as JSON and test the API call via Postman, it still displays as 123.456789. However, when I do a dump in the controller, it displays 123.45.
I am unsure why it displays as 123.456789 in Postman.

Topically relevant: Laravel Eloquent truncates the data type double and Laravel issue when printing a double field coming from the database

If you need to get the same value in Postman, you need to keep the formatted value as a string.
$number = 123.456789;
$formatted_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); 
return response()->json(['number' => $formatted_number]);


The reason why you are having this:
the  number_format()  helper function formats the number to two decimal places and then converts the float to a string representation as per the docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), which is why you get "123.45". but from the sample code provided, you are casting the string back to a float which is converted to a floating-point number with two decimal places.
Floating-point precision can lead to unexpected results  when the number is serialized again (such as converting to JSON).Since you are checking from Postman,  JSON encoding in PHP uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which can introduce precision issues. This is the reason why your  $float_number displays more decimal places than expected when encoded into JSON for postman
this might be helpful
PHP - Floating Number Precision

It seems like the issue might be related to how Laravel serializes the response data when returning JSON. Laravel by default uses json_encode() to serialize data, which may not respect the number of decimal places you've formatted.
To ensure that the JSON response reflects the formatting with two decimal places, you can explicitly round the number to two decimal places before returning it. Here's how you can do it:
$number = 123.456789; // Example number
// Round the number to 2 decimal places, then format number and cast  the number to float
$float_number = (float) number_format(round($number, 2), 2, '.', '');
// Return the float number in JSON response
return response()->json(['float_number' => $float_number]);

Above solution should display as 123.45 in Postman.
